# R: Plotting Columns of Points on Top of Each Other

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I am working with the R programming language.

I have the following data frame:

```
my_data <- dput(my_data)
structure(list(number_i_1 = c(9.14811534198728, 8.9275657742618, 
12.2626425289257, 11.1541226617826, 8.24541227315251, 9.29011983326233, 
7.90461585190617, 9.96914166332003, 10.4539377795271, 7.9675796247586, 
10.8608573941981, 8.30735339822199, 1.99434617291126, 5.16717357381871, 
14.3012387051036), number_i_2 = c(9.82508035629843, 11.337875507462, 
8.67260488451123, 11.2037152583314, 9.83831932165026, 10.8805046681, 
10.77946718646, 8.7972989662854, 7.98730961084559, 9.63695629657808, 
9.83725501468042, 9.35049306826633, 8.03576431691238, 11.8363195684276, 
10.3753351372418), number_i_3 = c(10.0297885217794, 8.9150666286516, 
8.97084876425627, 10.0812967754046, 10.8353399209151, 12.0396689374212, 
8.26039698010734, 10.0164406097398, 9.15875200326082, 10.1580335559883, 
10.894410502418, 9.66372987542513, 9.03145984132954, 12.0006448240653, 
12.1345128764205), number_i_4 = c(10.6774410989871, 9.00435929666813, 
10.245755473788, 9.35137662178161, 10.1632849937946, 10.6229340616454, 
9.36988749119136, 9.31309586091883, 9.60326542132072, 10.5866976216766, 
9.85136335793758, 9.05675556985556, 10.1394320010747, 10.3089579819193, 
8.82461740612389), number_i_5 = c(10.2381148240731, 10.2215440024877, 
9.89934619909394, 10.2298103380229, 9.4568626993797, 10.4092658579713, 
10.2963788105426, 8.62237136311543, 8.87961854317371, 10.8724614538803, 
9.91468834852646, 8.4431553024008, 10.4621972074183, 9.10679142679618, 
9.24362927074807)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("a", 
"a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6", "a7", "a8", "a9", "a10", 
"a11", "a12", "a13", "a14"))
```

The data looks something like this:

```
> head(my_data)
   number_i_1 number_i_2 number_i_3 number_i_4 number_i_5
a    9.148115   9.825080  10.029789  10.677441  10.238115
a1   8.927566  11.337876   8.915067   9.004359  10.221544
a2  12.262643   8.672605   8.970849  10.245755   9.899346
a3  11.154123  11.203715  10.081297   9.351377  10.229810
a4   8.245412   9.838319  10.835340  10.163285   9.456863
a5   9.290120  10.880505  12.039669  10.622934  10.409266
```

I would like to make the following graph:

[image]

- In the above graph, "1" represents the data from the column "number_i_1", "2" represents the data from "number_i_2", etc.
- The "red dots" represent the mean of each column.
- The "red line" is some "line of best fit" (e.g. linear, polynomial) that goes through all these points.

I was able to get the mean of all columns:

```
mean_vector = c(mean(my_data$number_i_1), mean(my_data$number_i_2), mean(my_data$number_i_3), mean(my_data$number_i_4), mean(my_data$number_i_5))
```

But from here, I am not sure how to plot (e.g. with ggplot2) the data points the way I want.

Can someone please show me how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ggplot`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

df <- tidyr::gather(my_data, "x")

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = value, group = 1)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_summary(fun = "mean", col = "red") +
  geom_smooth(col = "red", se = FALSE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using `matplot` and relatives.

```
matplot(t(my_data), pch=20, col=1)
matpoints(colMeans(my_data), pch=20, col='red')     
matlines(colMeans(my_data), lty=1, col='red')
```

[image]